# opengl shared memory layout and size

Tags: opengl, glsl

Given the following glsl declarations (this is just an example):

```c
struct S{
    f16vec3 a;
    float16_t b;
    f16vec3_t c;
    float16_t d;
};
shared float16_t my_float_array[100];
shared S my_S_array[100];
```

I have the following questions:

- How much shared memory will be used by a given declaration, in the above example for instance?
- Which memory layout is used for variables in shared memory? std140, std430 or something else?
- How does this play with bank conflicts?

I was able to get the total shared memory required by a program using *glGetProgramBinary* and skiping until the begining of the text part indicated by a line starting with "!!NV":

```
...
!!NVcp5.0
OPTION NV_shader_buffer_load;
OPTION NV_internal;
OPTION NV_gpu_program_fp64;
OPTION NV_shader_storage_buffer;
OPTION NV_bindless_texture;
OPTION NV_gpu_program5_mem_extended;
GROUP_SIZE 4 4 4;
SHARED_MEMORY 4480;
SHARED shared_mem[] = { program.sharedmem };
...
```

This is rather indirect though and does not tell much about the alignment/packing rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which memory layout is used for variables in shared memory? std140, std430 or something else?

It's implementation-defined.

The layouts applied to buffer-backed storage matter because code external to the shader needs to be able to access it. `shared` variables cannot be externally to the shader, so the layout of such variables is functionally implementation-defined.

In short, you cannot know for certain how much storage any particular `shared` variable declaration will consume. You can assume that it will take up *at least* as many bytes as is minimally required to store the data you asked to store. But that's about it.

> How does this play with bank conflicts?

"Banks" are not a concept which OpenGL or GLSL recognizes. It is therefore implementation-defined.

Comment: That's not the answer I was hopping for... seems like I will have to do my own testing.